How to create an array that will group each object inside that array by specific value
I have an array of objects

is it possible to make a query in mysql to generate an array of 2 arrays of object that are group by group_id.
Result:

if not how to do this in javascript, also the group ID needs to be dynamic.?

Time to quote the posting rules: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. — copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.". A rule so important it's literally in bold and all caps. So click [edit] and fix your post, please.

MySQL is a relational database, which means it can only return tabular results, not hierarchical ones.

You may consider using the newly available API Object.groupBy. Check its compatibility.


const input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    group_id: 1,
    name: "name 1 "
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    group_id: 1,
    name: "name 2 "
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 1,
    name: "name 3 "
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    group_id: 2,
    name: "name 4 "
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    group_id: 2,
    name: "name 5 "
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    group_id: 2,
    name: "name 6 "
  }
];

const output = Object.values(Object.groupBy(input, obj => obj.group_id));

console.log(output);



Using Array.reduce can achieve the same effect if you need to work with older browsers.


const input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    group_id: 1,
    name: "name 1 "
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    group_id: 1,
    name: "name 2 "
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 1,
    name: "name 3 "
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    group_id: 2,
    name: "name 4 "
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    group_id: 2,
    name: "name 5 "
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    group_id: 2,
    name: "name 6 "
  }
];

const output = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc[cur.group_id]) 
    acc[cur.group_id] = [];
  acc[cur.group_id].push(cur);
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(output);



